# Convert BufferedOutputStream to InputStream for Jersey REST response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, streaming

In my `getfile()` REST method I have a `BufferedOutputStream` that is being filled with data on on the `restDAO.readData()` call. This code previously passed a byte array in a file in the response, but due to memory limitations we are trying to implementing streaming. The `Response.ok()` method, from what I can tell, needs to return an implementation of `InputStream`.

Unfortunately I don't have access to change the `readData` method, and I cannot use the `easyStream` API.

What would be the best way to take the data in the `BufferedOutputStream` and put it into an InputStream using proper streaming technique? (without converting to a byte array)

```
@GET
public Response getFile(@Context javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

    // Stream is filled with data in this method.
    restDAO.readData(bufferedOutputStream);

    // How do I take data from bufferedOutputStream and put it into inputStream?
    // InputStream inputStream = ?

    return Response.ok(inputStream, mimeType).header("filename", getFileName()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to return a [StreamingOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) object:

```
Object body = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out)
    throws IOException {
        final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        // Stream is filled with data in this method.
        restDAO.readData(bufferedOutputStream);
    }
};

return Response.ok(body, mimeType).header("filename", getFileName()).build();
```